# Even or Odd program in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to write an even or odd program in angularJs.
In the below code I have defined my own user-defined service to identify whether a number is even or odd it will work fine when the value is hardcoded. But when I try to give realtime value using the input method I am unable to get the desired answer. Please help me with this.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myCtrl'>
    <input type='number' name='num' ng-model='num'><br>
    <b>The number Entered is {{num}} which is {{myUserService}} </b>
</div>
<script>
angular.module('myApp',[]).service('myService',function(){
            this.myFunc=function(x){
                if(x%2==0)
                    return 'EVEN';
                else
                    return 'ODD';
                };
            }).controller('myCtrl',function($scope,myService){
                $scope.myUserService= myService.myFunc($scope.num);
          });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

- List item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because ng-model does not fire on change.

Your code currently fires once, on load, at that point the value is `undefined` and it prints "ODD" and because there's nothing triggering input change, nothing is happening.

I would recommend listening to `keyup` event on the input by using `ng-keyup`, like in the example below:

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).service('myService', function() {
  this.myFunc = function(x) {

    if (Number(x) % 2 === 0)
      return 'EVEN';
    else
      return 'ODD';
  };
}).controller('myCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
  $scope.check = function(num) {
    $scope.myUserService = myService.myFunc(num);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myCtrl'>
  <input type='number' name='num' ng-model="num" ng-keyup='check(num)'><br>
  <b>The number Entered is {{num}} which is {{myUserService}} </b>
</div>
```